# Python print parameter inside []

Tags: python, arrays

can you help me with python parameters. i have problem with string #4. thank you

output is list[2]
but i need BMW

```
list = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]
x = len(list)
a = x - 1
car = 'list[%s]' % a
print car
```

Comment: It's simply `car = list[a]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. you have to do only `car = list[a]` which will give you 'BMW'.

```
myList = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]
x = len(myList)
a = x - 1
car = myList[a]
print(car)   # 'BMW'
```

I have renamed the variable name. While you are giving variable name just careful about the predefined/built in keywords because its not good approach to give variable/function name same as built in types as it masks the builtin type name.

Answer (score 0):

At first, don't use `list` as a variable, `list` is a keyword in python. Try some other name. And you are now printing the value of a which is an index not an element of the list. You have to use `list[a]` to print an element of a list positioned at index a.